# ggplot not recognizing variable for some levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the following data set and trying to generate a bar graph with it using ggplot. I've used this many times before with the same format but cannot get the gplot code to recognize factor 'Year' appropriately in this case, no matter how I reformat my data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Year<-c(2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017)
Strat<-c(0,0,5,5,10,10,15,15,20,20,0,0,5,5,10,10,15,15,20,20)
Scar<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
GDMean<-c(4,3,4,3,4,3,5,5,4,4,4,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,2)
GDSE<-c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
GPMean<-c(87,91,88,99,91,92,78,92,80,86,72,85,90,83,92,89,86,88,82,88)
GPSE<-c(2,2,3,1,3,2,3,2,2,2,6,4,3,4,2,3,3,2,5,4)
YZ<-cbind(Year,Strat,Scar,GDMean,GDSE,GPMean,GPSE)
YZ<-data.frame(YZ)
YZ$Strat<-as.factor(YZ$Strat)
YZ$Year<-as.factor(YZ$Year)
YZ$Scar<-as.factor(YZ$Scar)
YZ<-data.frame(YZ)

GRAPH<- ggplot(data=YZ,aes(x=YZ$Year, y=YZ$GPMean, fill=YZ$Scar))+geom_bargeom_bar(position='dodge',stat='identity',width=0.7)+
  facet_grid(. ~ YZ$Strat)+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=YZ$GPMean-YZ$GPSE, ymax=YZ$GPMean+YZ$GPSE), position = position_dodge(), width = 0.7)+ 
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),axis.line=elment_line(colour="black"),panel.border=element_blank(),legend.position="none")+
scale_fill_grey()+
ylab("Max")
GRAPH
```

Then I get something like this:

[bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFZHY.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to refer to columns of data frame using `$` inside `ggplot()` call

```
GRAPH <- ggplot(data = YZ, aes(x = Year, y = GPMean, fill = Scar)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Strat) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = GPMean - GPSE, ymax = GPMean + GPSE), 
                position = position_dodge(), width = 0.7) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  ylab("Max")
GRAPH
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>